# Scripts referenced by :r in post-deployment script show error

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I'm creating a DACPAC using a database project in Visual Studio 2017. I have a single post-deployment script (with a build action of PostDeploy), and several other .sql scripts that contain merge statements to fill out some lookup tables.

I'm following the directions in the post-deployment script template, and referencing the other .sql scripts using :r (e.g. :r .\ErrorMessageLookup.sql;).

No matter what I do, I'm getting a build error saying "72001: The included file [file path] does not exist. If I copy that file path from the error message and paste it into file explorer, the file comes up, so there doesn't appear to be any typos in there. I've been tearing my hair out on this one. All the related issues I can find on here deal with linked files from other projects, but these are just vanilla files contained in the database project file structure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have that file included in the project as anything other than "None" for the Build Properties?  Is the path actually correct in relation to the Post-Deploy script that calls it?  In the example here, it should be in the same folder as your post-deploy script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing the semicolon from the end of your `:r .\ErrorMessageLookup.sql;`?

I was similarly tearing my hair out on the same issue, and removing the semis caused SQLCMD to suddenly be able to map to the files.